# java8 use of function result alters further processing

Tags: java, validation, lambda

This is a Java 8 application using `Stream` and `javaslang.control.Validation` to have flow control over success/failure scenarios. I have a junit test performing the following:

```
@Autowired
MessageEntityRepository messageEntityRepository;
....
@Test
public void handleTest(){
  /* MyEvent is basically a container object used to create 
     something like HashMap for further processing */

  MyEvent event = prepareEvent(asList("Data.json", "Data2.json", "Data_badformat.json"));

  InboundResponse<Stream<InboundMessageResponse<MessageSuccess, MessageFailure>>>
                                            fileResponses = inboundService.handle(event);   

  fileResponses.getResponses().forEach(this::printResults);

  assertEquals(3,messageEntityRepository.count());
}

public void printResults(InboundMessageResponse<MessageSuccess, MessageFailure> responses){
    System.out.println("HELLO");
}
```

This is a test using `event` as a container object that collects records into an H2 database. The line `fileResponses.getResponses().forEach(this::printResults);` ends up just printing "Hello" to my console. The result of this test is that it passes with 3 records being inserted into my database.

Here's where it gets weird for me: if I remove the line `fileResponses.getResponses().forEach(this::printResults);` the test fails showing 0 records inserted.

It seems like I need something using the output of the handle method in order for the handle method to even be executed.

Comment: Streams are lazy, if you don’t have a terminal operation that does something with the stream contents then nothing happens, sounds like this is what you’re seeing.

Comment: What is an `InboundResponse`? What does `handle` return? What does `getResponses()` return? Your question lacks information.

Answer (score 1):

Streams are lazy, they won't execute anything unless given a terminal operation. The rest of the functions pipeline is a list of operations to perform on the stream, not an explicit call for execution. `forEach` is a terminal operation, so when it's present you get the stream values according to the callback. Other terminal operations are `collect` or `reduce`